# Trigger Firebase Job Dispatcher at a particular time

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I want to trigger Firebase Job Dispatcher at a particular time like `1498383000000L`. But the trigger method has a window where we specify the time. How do I overcome this?

```
 Job newJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()

            //update if any task with the given tag exists.
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)

            //Integrate the job you want to start.
            .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)

            .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")

            // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60))

            .build();

    return newJob;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate a difference between particular time in the future and now in seconds and set it as a `windowStart` parameter in `Trigger.executionWindow()` method. You can set the same value as a `windowEnd` parameter to make the job start as closest to that time as possible, but even in this case there is no guarantee the job starts in particularly that time.

From my experience the job starts usually not more than in a minute (sometimes in a few seconds) after the `windowStart` time when the `windowStart` and the`windowEnd` values are the same value.

In the example below the start time is calculated based on required job start time and a 60 seconds window is set for the job to start.

```
long timeInFuture = 1498383000000L;
int jobTime = Math.round((System.currentTimeMillis() - timeInFuture) / 1000);
Job newJob = null;
if (jobTime >= 0){
   newJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
            .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(jobTime, jobTime + 60))
            .build();
}

return newJob;
```